# Image crop based on Line/Corner detection with Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, canny-operator

I'm trying to automatically crop all the images from a dataset I have with Python. The problem is that the region of interest in each image is not fixed, so I can't use coordinates for cropping. Below is an example of an image from the dataset and an image showing where I want to crop. All the images look like that: lots of orange around, and in the center is the desired region for cropping.

Input Image:
[image]

Input Image with lines that need to be found and cropped:
[image]

Desired Output Image:

[image]

My problem is that I couldn't find any tool or method that could find the lines of this square and crop them, so I gave it a try with **Canny Edge Detection** and **Harris Corner Detector**. Canny seemed to be working on most of the images but couldn't crop them all correctly using the same parameters.

The code I used for Canny:

```
import cv2 
import os
import numpy as np

input_folder = "./dataset/"
output_folder = "./output_dataset/"

if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".JPEG"):
        # Read the image
        image_path = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)

        # Setting parameter values 
        t_lower = 10  # Lower Threshold 10
        t_upper = 70  # Upper threshold 70
        
        # Convert the image to grayscale
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                
        # Apply GaussianBlur to reduce noise and improve contour detection
        #blurred = cv2.blur(img, (3,3))
        blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
        
        # Applying the Canny Edge filter 
        edge = cv2.Canny(blurred, t_lower, t_upper) 
        
        # Find contours in the edged image
        # Example of contour area filtering
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edge, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours = [cnt for cnt in contours if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 10]

        
        pts=np.argwhere(edge>0)
        y1,x1=pts.min(axis=0)
        y2,x2=pts.max(axis=0)
        cropped=img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        
        file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)

        # Save the cropped image with the original filename and "_cropped" suffix
        output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{file_name}_cropped.jpg")
        cv2.imwrite(output_path, cropped)
```

**Correct Crop with Canny Example**

Input Image:
[image]

Canny Edge Detection:
[image]

Output Image:

[image]

**Inorrect Crop with Canny Example**

Input Image:
[image]

Canny Edge Detection:
[image]

Output Image:

[image]

Also, I thought of using Harris Corner Detector after applying Canny to the images that didn't crop quite well. By using the Harris Corner Detector, I would get the two farthest detections on the Y-axis of the image and crop it based on them. But I wasn't able to do that correctly; either way, it seems that it would crop most of the images incorrectly:

Harris Corner Detector Output from the previous wrong cropped image with Canny:

[image]

Also, I tried detecting vertical and horizontal lines with HoughLines with OpenCV, but it didn't work either. Do you have any suggestions for my problem?

**Thanks in advance!!**

Comment: Do you want to use `mouseevent` to crop?

Comment: @toyotaSupra I haven't heard of `mouseevent`. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Almost never use Canny.  Threshold on color using cv2.inRange followed by morphology to clean up

Comment: ignore "mouseevent". that means *you* get to select a rectangle on every picture.

Answer (score 1):

[image: This is what I got after some pre-processing]

This is definitely not the most general way, but since what you don't want is very orange (and has high values on the red channel), you can filter these pixels out by some threshold:

```
red = image[:,:,0].copy()
mask_red_high = (red>180)
red[mask_red_high] = 0
```

After that, I got a very grainy picture, which I dilated:

```
kernel = np.ones((20, 20), np.uint8)
red = cv2.morphologyEx(red, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)
```

Then it's pretty straight-forward:

```
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(red, (5, 5), 0) # bluring...
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 150) # edges...
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(red, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # contours...
sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True) # sort by area...
contour = sorted_contours[1].reshape((-1, 1, 2)) # this one is the second contour, since I couldn't filter out the edges of the image...
epsilon = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True) # get epsilon
approximated_square = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True) # get square
contoured_image = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(contoured_image, [approximated_square], -1, (255, 255, 255), 2) # draw the square as white
cv2.drawContours(contoured_image, sorted_contours[1], -1, (0, 0, 0), 5) # scatter the simple approximation of the contour
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approximated_square) # get params for cropping
cropped_image = contoured_image[y-10:y + h + 10, x - 10:x + w + 10] # cropping...
```

Would tinker a bit more with dynamic thresholds though, maybe think about Otsu or some other method

**V2.0:**

I added a few improvements, so that the code would work better on other pictures as well. Namely:

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("leaf2.jpg"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image = im.copy()
contoured_image = image.copy()

red = image[:,:,0].copy()
mask_red_high = (red>170)
red[mask_red_high] = 0
kernel = np.ones((30, 30), np.uint8)
red = cv2.morphologyEx(red, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(red, (5, 5), 0) # bluring...
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 150) # edges...
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(red, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # contours...
filtered_contours = [contour for contour in contours if 45000 < cv2.contourArea(contour) < 55000] # filter contours according to their area
sorted_contours = sorted(filtered_contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True) # sort by area...
contour = sorted_contours[0].reshape((-1, 1, 2)) # After filter, there should be only one contour
epsilon = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True) # get epsilon
approximated_square = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True) # get square
contoured_image = image.copy() # copy image
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approximated_square) # get params for cropping
cv2.rectangle(contoured_image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), 5) # draw the square as white
cv2.drawContours(contoured_image, contour, -1, (0, 0, 0), 5) # scatter the simple approximation of the contour
cropped_image = contoured_image[y-10:y + h + 10, x - 10:x + w + 10] # cropping...
```

This worked for all three images.. yet again, not the most robust way.

[image: first pic]
[image: second pic]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I wasn't able to reproduce the code cause I get a "list index out of range" error at "sorted_contours[1]....". Is there something that I'm missing? Thanks anyway!

Comment: which format is your image in? I usually convert them to RGB from BGR
try this when reading the image `im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("leaf.jpg"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: or if you don't want to convert it to RGB, then just select the red channel from the BGR format: `red = image[:,:,2]`

Comment: Thanks, now I'm able to reproduce the code. It works for the image you posted but it's not the case with the other images in the dataset. For example try these two: https://i.imgur.com/iBpdUvb.jpg and https://i.imgur.com/paN59qc.jpg

Comment: I came up with a way to do so, exactly with these three images. I got the area of all filtered contours and I specified that there should be an acceptable range (between 45000 and 55000). After that it was all the same, DM me to give you the change if you want

Comment: I edited the code, a robuster way even would be to get the rectangle for all contours and to check where the aspect ratio is almost 1:1 (since the window looks like a square)...

Comment: nice answer to a decent question.

Comment: Thanks @D.L I still think that there is room for improvement, I really don't like the fixed threshold. OP would have to check what their data looks like across all images...

Comment: @pchi does this answer your question? Please consider marking what I wrote, if you consider it correct.